# set ViewPager current item with animation

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-pagetransformer

I have a viewpager and I have used a simple page transformer.
The animation works on swiping the viewpager but it does not work when i call

`mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);`

the page changes but without any animation. How do I apply the animation to the viewpager even when the page item is changed by clicking the next/previous button

Comment: Check this Link it might help you https://www.spaceotechnologies.com/make-android-viewpager-intro-screen-page-transformer-animation/

Answer (score 0):

there's a `smoothScroll` parameter in `setCurrentItem` method if you check the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager#setcurrentitem_5)

try replacing

`mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);`

with

`mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position, true);`

(i haven't checked if it is working, but it might work)

Comment: nope it does not work. btw I did not downvote your answer

Comment: `smoothScroll` without boolean parameter uses smooth scroll by default

Comment: @PembaTamang it's alright, could you post your page transformer?

Comment: its ok..I did it by simulating swipes on the screen

Comment: oh.. great!! :)